# Need Help Deploying Celery Beat and a Celery Worker for Django on Azure App Services with Azure Cache for Redis using Systemd and a Startup Script

Tags: django, azure, celery, systemd

I am trying to deploy a django webapp to azure with a celery beat and worker instance running in the background. I've tried using a config file, a startup script, and systemd to deploy the celery instances. But I've been having problems getting the .services files to run. Here are my systemd .service files;

celerybeat.service

```
 [Unit]
 Description=Celery Beat Service
 After=network.target
 [Service]
 Type=simple
 User=celery
 Group=celery
 EnvironmentFile=/etc/conf.d/celery_config
 WorkingDirectory=/home/site/wwwroot/celery
 ExecStart= /bin/sh -c '${CELERY_BIN} -A ${CELERY_APP} beat  \
     --pidfile=${CELERYBEAT_PID_FILE} \
     --logfile=${CELERYBEAT_LOG_FILE} --loglevel=${CELERYD_LOG_LEVEL}'

Restart=always

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

celeryworker.service

```
[Unit]
Description=Celery Worker Service
After=network.target

[Service]
Type=simple
User=celery
Group=celery
EnvironmentFile=/etc/conf.d/celery_config
WorkingDirectory=/home/site/wwwroot/celery
ExecStart= /bin/sh -c '${CELERY_BIN} -A ${CELERY_APP} worker  \
    --pidfile=${CELERYD_PID_FILE} \
    --logfile=${CELERYD_LOG_FILE} --loglevel=${CELERYD_LOG_LEVEL}'

Restart=always

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

The celery config file is the following, celery_config;

```
# Name of nodes to start
# here we have a single node
CELERYD_NODES="w1"
# or we could have three nodes:
#CELERYD_NODES="w1 w2 w3"

# Absolute or relative path to the 'celery' command:
CELERY_BIN="/home/site/wwwroot/celery"
#CELERY_BIN="/virtualenvs/def/bin/celery"

# App instance to use
# comment out this line if you don't use an app
CELERY_APP="kinduwa"
# or fully qualified:
#CELERY_APP="proj.tasks:app"

# How to call manage.py
CELERYD_MULTI="multi"

# Extra command-line arguments to the worker
CELERYD_OPTS="--time-limit=300 --concurrency=8"

# - %n will be replaced with the first part of the nodename.
# - %I will be replaced with the current child process index
#   and is important when using the prefork pool to avoid race conditions.
CELERYD_PID_FILE="/var/run/celery/%n.pid"
CELERYD_LOG_FILE="/home/LogFiles/%n%I.log"
CELERYD_LOG_LEVEL="INFO"

# you may wish to add these options for Celery Beat
CELERYBEAT_PID_FILE="/var/run/celery/beat.pid"
CELERYBEAT_LOG_FILE="/home/LogFiles/celery/beat.log"
```

next my celery.py file in my django app;

```
import os

from celery import Celery
from django.conf import settings

# settings.configure()

# if settings.DEBUG:
#     setting_file = 'kinduwa.settings'
# else:
setting_file = 'kinduwa.production'


# set the default Django settings module for the 'celery' program.
os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', setting_file)

app = Celery('kinduwa')
app.config_from_object('kinduwa')

# Using a string here means the worker doesn't have to serialize
# the configuration object to child processes.
# - namespace='CELERY' means all celery-related configuration keys
#   should have a `CELERY_` prefix.
app.config_from_object('django.conf:settings', namespace='CELERY')

# Load task modules from all registered Django app configs.
app.autodiscover_tasks()

@app.task(bind=True)
def debug_task(self):
    print(f'Request: {self.request!r}')

# To start the worker process for development, you must run the following commands in separate terminals
# celery -A kinduwa beat -l INFO
# celery -A kinduwa worker -l INFO
# make sure your local redis server is also running
# type 'celery --help' for more info
```

finally here is my startup script that actually runs on startup of my app service;

```
apt-get update
apt-get install -y systemd


mkdir /var/run/celery/
mkdir /etc/conf.d/

cp celery_config /etc/conf.d/
cp celerybeat.service /etc/systemd/system/
cp celeryworker.service /etc/systemd/system/

chmod 644 /etc/systemd/system/celerybeat.service
chmod 644 /etc/systemd/system/celeryworker.service

/etc/init.d/dbus start

systemctl daemon-reload

systemctl start celerybeat
systemctl start celeryworker

gunicorn --bind=0.0.0.0 --timeout 600 kinduwa.wsgi
```

The current error that I've been looking to solve is the "failed to start celerybeat.service: Unknown unit : celerybeat.service"

```
2021-05-13T04:07:54.654058469Z Created symlink /etc/systemd/system/getty.target.wants/getty@tty1.service â†’ /lib/systemd/system/getty@.service.
2021-05-13T04:07:54.659312989Z Created symlink /etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/remote-fs.target â†’ /lib/systemd/system/remote-fs.target.
2021-05-13T04:07:54.668816506Z Created symlink /etc/systemd/system/sysinit.target.wants/systemd-timesyncd.service â†’ /lib/systemd/system/systemd-timesyncd.service.
2021-05-13T04:07:54.727944856Z Adding group `systemd-journal' (GID 103) ...
2021-05-13T04:07:54.742460987Z Done.
2021-05-13T04:07:55.287951738Z Setting up libpam-systemd:amd64 (232-25+deb9u12) ...
2021-05-13T04:07:55.387856718Z debconf: unable to initialize frontend: Dialog
2021-05-13T04:07:55.388996844Z debconf: (TERM is not set, so the dialog frontend is not usable.)
2021-05-13T04:07:55.389631459Z debconf: falling back to frontend: Readline
2021-05-13T04:07:55.390632182Z debconf: unable to initialize frontend: Readline
2021-05-13T04:07:55.391113593Z debconf: (Can't locate Term/ReadLine.pm in @INC (you may need to install the Term::ReadLine module) (@INC contains: /etc/perl /usr/local/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/perl/5.24.1 /usr/local/share/perl/5.24.1 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/perl5/5.24 /usr/share/perl5 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/perl/5.24 /usr/share/perl/5.24 /usr/local/lib/site_perl /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/perl-base .) at /usr/share/perl5/Debconf/FrontEnd/Readline.pm line 7.)
2021-05-13T04:07:55.392316820Z debconf: falling back to frontend: Teletype
2021-05-13T04:07:55.509303290Z Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.24-11+deb9u4) ...
2021-05-13T04:07:55.525179753Z Processing triggers for dbus (1.10.32-0+deb9u1) ...
2021-05-13T04:07:55.604052853Z Starting system message bus: dbus.
2021-05-13T04:07:55.635939281Z Failed to start celerybeat.service: Unknown unit: celerybeat.service
2021-05-13T04:07:55.636724399Z See system logs and 'systemctl status celerybeat.service' for details.
2021-05-13T04:07:55.641978419Z Failed to start celeryworker.service: Unknown unit: celeryworker.service
2021-05-13T04:07:55.642636034Z See system logs and 'systemctl status celeryworker.service' for details.
2021-05-13T04:07:56.094144240Z [2021-05-13 04:07:56 +0000] [785] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 20.0.4
2021-05-13T04:07:56.095453669Z [2021-05-13 04:07:56 +0000] [785] [INFO] Listening at: http://0.0.0.0:8000 (785)
2021-05-13T04:07:56.096002982Z [2021-05-13 04:07:56 +0000] [785] [INFO] Using worker: sync
2021-05-13T04:07:56.099059052Z [2021-05-13 04:07:56 +0000] [788] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 788
```

I am trying to get this celery services to run, but I'm having a lot of trouble, getting them to work and also navigating this system in general. I'm wondering if anyone has immediate problems with my current setup, or knows what I might be missing or haven't done. I think I've exhausted all the stack overflow articles pertaining to this topic. Thanks again and let me know if I need to add more information to this write up.

Also if you have an easier solution or way to do this deployment please let me know!